# Which physical quantity is represented by the surface integral of magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields

The answer is given as magnetic flux in one place and Gauss law of magnetism in another. So which one is correct and why?

Comment: The integral of the magnetic field over a surface is indeed the magnetic flux through that surface. Gauss's law of magnetism states that the magnetic flux though a closed surface is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnetic field always circulate (in steady current situations) like this

[image]

So, if you take any closed volume  *containing* the magnetic field you will find that field lines enter from one side and leaves from the other side, therefore, for any closed volume 
$$ \oint_A \mathbf{B} \cdot d\mathbf{A} = 0$$ By [divergence theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) $$ \oint_V (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}) dV = \oint_A \mathbf{B} \cdot d\mathbf{A} $$ Therefore, we can write 
$$ \oint_V  (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}) dV = 0$$ and since, this is true for any volume, therefore $$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} =0~~~~~~~(1)$$

The equation (1) is called the **Gauss’ Law of Magnetism** . However, if we take any closed surface (please understand that closed surface is different from closed volume, a Circle is a closed surface but a sphere is a closed volume) so taking surface integral around any closed surface, i.e. $$ \int_S \mathbf{B} \cdot d\mathbf{S}$$ is not necessarily zero and is called the magnetic flux.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

[Magnetic flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux) is the surface integral of the magnetic field.

[Guass's law of magnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_magnetism) describes a (so-far universal) observation about magnetic flux: The total magnetic flux through any closed surface is zero.